# Sipp with pcap installation on windows

Tags: sip

I am trying to install sipp with pcap-replay on winows7.

I have installed cygwnin, libncurse, and winpcap. I was trying to patch cygwin with IPv6 using the URL http://cygwin.win6.jp/cygwin-ipv6/, but it couldn't get the setup.ini file.

So I copied to local directory and upgrade, but it said no new updates.

And if I try to complie sipp. it gives error
$ ./configure.ac --with-pcap
./configure.ac: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `[SIPp],'
./configure.ac: line 3:`AC_INIT([SIPp], [3.3], [sipp-users@lists.sourceforge.net], [sipp])'

Could anyone help me in getting sipp be installed on windows?

Comment: I haven't tested it with IPv6 and it may be based on outdated SIPp version, but you may check SIPp-MinGW (SIPp ported to MinGW).

Answer (score 0):

I download sipp.3.3.990 it has ./configure and was able to install on Linux.
But now on windows it still fails saying ncurse is not present. But I have downloaded it.

How do I troubleshoot it from here?

Comment: is ncurses installed in standard directory? If not, did you provide the path to ncurses headers in configure parameters (check configure --help)?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps to generate configure from configure.ac.

```
$> autoreconf -i
```

Now, you will see a configure file created at the same location.

To run the above command, following packages are required: automake,ncurses-devel,libncurses,M4 and autoconf.
if any of the above packages are missing run the cygwin setup file again and select the packages on the package selection screen and click install.